# Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку проигрывался звук?

Tags: javascript, html, аудио

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку **"Заказать билет"** [input type="submit"] воспроизводился звук.
Проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку **"Заказать билет"** у меня просто обновляется страница и все, никакой звук не воспроизводится. Но если вызывать функцию через консоль в браузере (F12), то она работает как надо.

```
<input type="submit" form="order_form" value="Заказать билет" onclick="order();"></input>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function order()
        {
            var audio = new Audio();
            audio.src = 'src/sound.mp3';
            audio.autoplay = true;
            alert("Ваш заказ был принят, ждите звонка в дверь");

            return true;
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
function playSound(sound) {
  var song = document.getElementById(sound);
  song.volume = 1;
  if (song.paused) {
    song.play();
  } else {
    song.pause();
  }
}
```

```html
<audio id="sound"><source src="https://ozarnik.ru/uploads/files/2019-02/1549784984_dj-ozarnik-primite-zakaz.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
<input type="submit" value="Заказать билет" form="order_form" id="button" class="button" onclick="playSound('sound'); setTimeout('alert(\'Откладываем второе событие\')', 7000)"">
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в обновлении страницы если я правильно понимаю, в таком случае всё более менее просто. 
Есть два варианта.

Отключить событие нажатия на кнопку по умолчанию:

`<input type="submit" id="submitBtn" onclick="drawShelves(); return false;">`

Отключить событие отправки формы по умолчанию:

`<form id="mainForm" onsubmit="return false;">`

Но в обоих случаях вам нужно каким-либо образом без перезагрузки страницы отправить данные на сервер. Самый верный способ -- использовать Ajax запрос.

Вот тут есть пошаговый гайд как реализовать это с помощью ajax
https://fructcode.com/ru/blog/how-to-send-html-form-with-ajax/